# Obtaining training Error using Caret package in R

Tags: r, algorithm, machine-learning, analytics, r-caret

I am using **caret package** in order to train a **K-Nearest Neigbors** algorithm. For this, I am running this code:

```
Control <- trainControl(method="cv", summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, classProb=T)

tGrid=data.frame(k=1:100)

trainingInfo <- train(Formula, data=trainData, method = "knn",tuneGrid=tGrid,
                              trControl=Control, metric =  "ROC")
```

As you can see, I am interested in obtain the AUC parameter of the ROC. This code works good but returns the **testing** error (which the algorithm uses for tuning the k parameter of the model) as the mean of the error of the CrossValidation folds. I am interested in return, in addition of the testing error, the **training** error (the mean across each fold of the error obtained with the training data). ¿How can I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is a bad idea on multiple levels. You will grossly over-estimate the area under the ROC curve. Consider the 1-NN model: you will have perfect predictions every time.

To do this, you will need to run `train` again and modify the `index` and `indexOut` objects:

```
library(caret)

set.seed(1)
dat <- twoClassSim(200)

set.seed(2)
folds <- createFolds(dat$Class, returnTrain = TRUE)

Control <- trainControl(method="cv", 
                        summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, 
                        classProb=T,
                        index = folds,
                        indexOut = folds)

tGrid=data.frame(k=1:100)

set.seed(3)
a_bad_idea <- train(Class ~ ., data=dat, 
                    method = "knn",
                    tuneGrid=tGrid,
                    trControl=Control, metric =  "ROC")
```

Max

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Probably I did not explain it correctly... I need to return BOTH, the training error and the test error, without running it 2 times. Not only the train error.

The reason I want to do it is for evaluate if a bad result is due to overfitting or underfitting.